# how to get output of table on page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I create a table I get data from the database using the backend I just want to show the output of the table on the page the output will not be visible

This is the code of my `table.js`

```
//import Data from './TextForm';

function Table(props) {
    console.log('type ', typeof (props.Data));
    console.log('data ', props.Data)
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Text No</th>
                    <th>TextArea</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {props.Data ?
                    Object.entries(props.Data).map((key,value)=> {
                        console.log('Key',key);
                        {
                            <tr key={value}>
                                <td>{key.textId}</td>
                                <td>{key.textArea}</td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    })
                    : null
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    )
}
export default Table;
```

this is props. data where I get the data and define prop. data I get data from the backend I connected the frontend for getting and storing data

---

### Edit

```
function TextForm(props) {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [submittext,setsubmittext]=useState(null);
    const [Data,setData]=useState([]);

    const handleOnClickUpperCase = () => {
        var newText = text.toUpperCase();
        setText(newText);
    }
    const handleOnClickLowerCase = () => {
        var newText = text.toLowerCase();
        setText(newText);
    }

    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        setText(e.target.value);
    }
    

    const handleOnPreview = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setsubmittext(text);
        // console.log(text);
        const ROOT_URL='https://localhost:7113/';
        var formData={
            Textarea:text
        }
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}api/demo-text`, formData, {
            headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",  'Content-Type': 'application/json'} 
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log('successs')
            //handle success
            
            setData(response);
            console.log('response ',Data);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log('error')
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
        })   
    }
    return (
        <>
           
            <div className="container">
                <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                <p>Enter Text Here:</p>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <textarea className="form-control" value={text} onChange={handleOnChange} id="mybox" rows="8"></textarea>
                </div>
                 <Table Data={Data} />
                {text === text.toLowerCase() ? <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleOnClickUpperCase}>Convert to Upper Case</button> : <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleOnClickLowerCase}>Convert to Lower Case</button>}
                <button className="btn btn-primary mx-3" onClick={handleOnPreview}>submit</button>
            </div>
            <hr></hr>
            <div className="container my-4" >
                <h1>{props.sum}</h1>
                <p>Text Word {text.split(" ").length} and Character is {text.length}</p>
                <p>{0.008 * text.split(" ").length} Minutes to Read</p>
            </div>
            <hr></hr>
            <div className="container my-4">
                <h2>Preview Your Text</h2>
                <p>{submittext}</p>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}
```

the output of prop.data

[image]

Comment: Please, provide more details because it is not clear where is the problem.

Comment: it will not show the output on view page

Comment: which types of details do you want

Comment: Would you provide an example of the props.Data.

Comment: add `return` in .map `return { <tr key={value}> ....`

Comment: Can u give us the sampled data which ur props are receiving

Comment: Yes, as @Usama mentioned you need to return the `tr` from the map method.

Comment: @Mina i tried to return but it will not work

Comment: @gouravkumar, So please provide a sample of `prop.Data`, so we can do debugging.

Comment: @gouravkumar when u r console.log('data ', props.Data) what is the output ?

Comment: they give all data from the starting I stored

Comment: @gouravkumar Axios is sending request to localhost, so the data will not return in our case, would you console.log the `prop.Data` and send us an example of the data, or provide us a live URL to get the data.

Comment: @wait I update the question

Comment: yeah! i update the question and add output of props.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here have iterator objects array so pls try the following the code see I created an example as your same array object as you shared img pls find an example here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-monad-hn9vu4?file=/src/index.js).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Data = {
  data: {
    result: [
      { textId: 1, textarea: "test" },
      { textId: 2, textarea: "1234" },
      { textId: 3, textarea: null },
      { textId: 4, textarea: null },
    ]
  }
};

function Table(props) {
  console.log("type ", typeof props.Data);
  console.log("data ", props.Data);
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Text No</th>
          <th>TextArea</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props?.Data?.data?.result?.map((item) => (
          <>
            <tr key={item.textId}>
              <td>{item.textId}</td>
              <td>{item.textarea}</td>
            </tr>
          </>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Table Data={Data} />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: It will work and another issue when I use the project this output will show when I click on submit button but I want it will show without clicking on submit button

Comment: call API in `useEffect`  hooks

Answer (score 0):

So you have to iterate over `props.Data.data.result` instead of `props.Data`, You don't need the Object.entries(),
and make the initial value of the Data = {} instead of [].

```
const [Data, setData] = useState({});
```

In the conditional JSX code, you need to check if the object has keys or not, and you don't need Object.entries method, just go with `props.Data.data.result.map()`, Also you have to return `tr` from the map method as @Usama mentioned.

```
         {Object.keys(props.Data).length ?
                props.Data.data.result.map((key,value)=> {
                    return (<tr key={value}>
                            <td>{key.textId}</td>
                            <td>{key.textArea}</td>

                        </tr>)
                    
                })
                : null
            }
```

Comment: this error occur `Uncaught TypeError: props.Data.data is undefined`

Comment: Yes, also I think, you need to set initial value of the Data = {} instead of [] `const [Data,setData]=useState({});`, also in the condition in the JSX code, you need to check if the object has a keys or not, `Object.keys(props.Data).length ? ... : null`

Comment: yes object has a key i recently checked that

Comment: when i use {} instead of [] data doesn't get from database it show empty

Comment: it is just an initial value it shouldn't affect anything related to resetting it.

Comment: I just update the answer, please check again.